# Extend types from existing node modules library with a new types

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, custom-type, openseadragon

I am using the openseadragon library with @types/openseadragon

the library has a Viewer object that I need to extend

now I have another library called openseadraonselection without types.
I found a  nice types file here:

https://github.com/alvaromartmart/types-openseadragonselection/blob/master/index.d.ts

the issue is when I added it to my custom types file, it overrides the openseadragon basic types

even if I declare something like  that it will override the openseadragon object:

```
declare module 'openseadragon' {
}
```

basically, I need to add an object to the viewer object  so I will be able to do the following:

```
viewer.selection({....})
```

the viewer is from types Openseadragon.Viewer and selection is the new type

Comment: I think you already have variable defined in your file name openseadragon. So why not you are using the import/as syntax while importing openseadragon?

Comment: @souravsatyam thx.  can you add an example ?
I need the viewer.selection and selection does not exist in the basic openseadragon libraray (Openseadragon.viewer)

Comment: import {openseadragon as os} from '@types/openseadragon';
Then access the viewer object using os.Viewer etc. Similarly you can import some other library that is overriding with some other name,

Comment: @souravsatyam  but still then I dont have the object "selection" in the viewer 

const viewer: os.viewer = new Openseadragon......

viewer.selection ... - > does not exists
is it possible to extent the types?

Comment: I give a look in documentations of OpenseaDragon but can't locate key "Selection". http://openseadragon.github.io/docs/ ... Can you share me any reference link where selection property is available\

Comment: @souravsatyam that what I said ,  its not avaliable in the openseadragon types but its available here :https://github.com/alvaromartmart/types-openseadragonselection/blob/master/index.d.ts

so my qeustion if its possible to extend it